# Backup of server database to local machine

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to backup of my server database to my local machine, i go through previous question asked in SO [Create Sql Server Backup on Local Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130944/create-sql-server-backup-on-local-machine) which is quite helpful, but still i am not able to take backup of DB.
it said backup is complete. but nothing was there in my Machine.
May be my drive is not in Mapping, which is mentioned in second point in that question.
what should i have to do, please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- create a share on your machine; say to directory `d:\dbbackup`. Allow it to be written to by the Everyone account. Let's call the share "dbbackup". It's now `\\yourMachine\dbbackup`. Confirm you can read and write to this share from your server via Windows Explorer.
- run this in SSMS:

```
BACKUP DATABASE YourDatabase
  TO DISK = '\\yourMachine\dbBackup\YourDatabase.BAK';
```

- your backup is now on `\\yourMachine\dbbackup`

Comment: i create a folder Share on D:\, so now do i need to put my machine name instead of yourMachine.  I am doing this "BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase
  TO DISK = '\\yourMachine\Share\MyDatabase.BAK';" is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, use your PC's name instead of `yourMachine`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to a remote server - which I believe is the case - when you select drive options, it is showing you the drive options on the 'server', not your local machine. So whatever you chose (or even the default one) will get saved on the server, not your local machine. Try looking for the backup file on the server in the directory you chose.

If your local machine is on the same network as the remote machine, you can use the script in the other question and backup. You can also map the drive on the remote machine, and then it should be available for you to choose (if you are using the GUI).

Answer (score 0):

Subeer,

When you backup a SQL Server database, it goes in an awkward spot by default. Typically, you can define this path.

However - check here:
C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/

In there should be a MSSQL folder or possibly MSSQL10.SQL2008EXPRESS (depends on what version of SQL SERVER). Open that, and inside should be a "Backups" folder.

Comment: If its 2005, I think the folder is MSSQL.1