# SQL Server generating script for earlier versions

Tags: sql-server

I had applied for a job vacancy and they asked to make a task in order to be hired, so the task was a website needed a database and I sent the task through email but they replied "Please send me database as backup file or scripted as SQL Server version 2012 or earlier"

I just need a way to make script of version 2012 while I created the database using SQL Server 2014

What to do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Sql Server Backup on Local Machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130944/create-sql-server-backup-on-local-machine)

Comment: If you're writing the database from scratch it's better to just write the scripts yourself and forget about all bloated scripting that SSMS creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the backups, I don't think there is a way, the server will create files compatible with its own version. Newer ones can recognize them, but not earlier ones. Neither helps detaching the DB files and sending them, as they have the same limitation.

Generating scripts from SSMS is the best way to go if you have an existing DB. You can set the compatibility level in `Tools => Options => SQL Server Object Explorer => Scripting => Script for server versions`, which lets you choose which version will the code attempt to be compatible with. Of course you need to make sure that you don't use features introduced in latter versions.

The ideal way is still, if you design and implement the DB yourself, to write the scripts yourself and taking care of compatibility, *avoiding the visual designers altogether*.

Comment: Mr alejandro , sir i did what you said but where to find the scripts to send it  to the recruiter ? thanks in advance @Alejandro

Comment: That doesn't generate anything, it's just a configuration to limit SSMS to a specific version when scripting. The actual work it's still done in the same way, the `script object as...` context menu all over the object explorer or the `generate scripts` option in task context menu. Those are affected by the parameter, but otherwise function as always.